Mongo C++ Driver: Insert
This update is based on a previous review where I tried creating a WriteConfig and a WriteConfigBuilder. I have updated this so I am only using the Config part and not the Builder.
The wire protocol for Mongo Insert is:
You will notice that of the 7 parameters 5 are optional and one is implied due to context. So I have shaped my API so that the required parameters is part of the interface and the user can pass the optional parameters in a separate optional config object (Rather than having a mass of insert() functions taking different number of parameters).
I am using this as an example. Because the findAndModify API has 13 optional parameters (and I want to use a similar patter for all the API). If this looks sensible then I can use this standard pattern.
class Collection
{
     ... STUFF removed.
     template<typename T>
     InsertResult   insert(std::vector<T> const& data, InsertConfig const& config = InsertConfig{});
     template<typename... T>
     InsertResult   insert(std::tuple<T...> const& data, InsertConfig const& config = InsertConfig{});
};

The optional config object is then defined like this:
class InsertConfig
{
    std::optional<bool>             ordered;
    std::optional<std::uint32_t>    maxTimeMS;
    std::optional<WriteConcern>     writeConcern;
    std::optional<bool>             bypassDocumentValidation;
    std::optional<std::string>      comment;

    public:
        std::optional<bool>             const& getOrdered()            const   {return ordered;}
        std::optional<std::uint32_t>    const& getMaxTimeMS()          const   {return maxTimeMS;}
        std::optional<WriteConcern>     const& getWriteConcern()       const   {return writeConcern;}
        std::optional<bool>             const& getBypassDocumentValidation()   const   {return bypassDocumentValidation;}
        std::optional<std::string>      const& getComment()            const   {return comment;}

        InsertConfig& setOrdered(bool value)                    {ordered.emplace(value);                    return *this;}
        InsertConfig& setMaxTimeMS(std::uint32_t value)         {maxTimeMS.emplace(value);                  return *this;}
        InsertConfig& setWriteConcern(WriteConcern value)       {writeConcern.emplace(value);               return *this;}
        InsertConfig& setBypassDocumentValidation(bool value)   {bypassDocumentValidation.emplace(value);   return *this;}
        InsertConfig& setComment(std::string value)             {comment.emplace(value);                    return *this;}
};

This allows the interface to be called like this:
mongo["DB"]["Collection"].insert(peopleVector,
                                 InsertConfig{}
                                     .setOrdered(true)
                                     .setComment("Add people")
                                     // Add more optional param here
                                 );

Nothing interesting to review in the actual insert() function.
